# Can't install RHmm package from archive

Tags: r

I am trying to install a package from a downloaded [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RHmm/index.html)  `RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz`

```
install.packages(  path_to_file,   repos=NULL, dependencies=TRUE)
```

...

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/tars/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'RHmm' ...
** package 'RHmm' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (GCC) 12.2.0'
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -w -D_RDLL_    -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Kmeans.cpp -o Kmeans.o
....
....
cDMatrix.cpp:497:24: error: too few arguments to function 'void dspev_(const char*, const char*, const int*, double*, double*, double*, const int*, double*, int*, size_t, size_t)'
....
cDMatrix.cpp:538:20: error: too few arguments to function 'void dspev_(const char*, const char*, const int*, double*, double*, double*, const int*, double*, int*, size_t, size_t)'
....
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:272: cDMatrix.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RHmm'
* removing 'C:/Users/tars/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/RHmm'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/tars/Desktop/RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can I still install this wonderful package or is it hopelessly outdated?

Here is my session

```
sessionInfo()
```

...

```
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

time zone: Europe/Kiev
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0 tools_4.3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the author and this wonderful person made bug fixes.
Now the package can be installed

```
install.packages("RHmm", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Answer (score 1):

It was removed from CRAN in 2014 because of unfixed errors:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RHmm/index.html .  Do you think you could fix those, and the ones you are seeing?  I'd guess it won't be easy, but it would be possible, if you know enough about the things it is doing and the code that implements them.

To do it, you could fork the source from either R-forge or Github, and work through the errors to fix them.

I'm not familiar with the package, but if it really is a "wonderful package", maybe it's worth doing this.